# Blocking Boost Asio Worker Threads

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm developing a network server based on **Boost::Asio**.

I have a `boost::thread_group` of IO worker threads which I use to call `boost::asio::io_service::run( )`

When network activity occurs **ASIO** uses one of these worker threads to process the activity (eg. Accept or Receive).

My application then does some work, possibly some calculation, possibly some other IO (via boost) and possibly some database activity.

I'd like to know what the implications are of doing said work within these threads. Specifically:

- Does carrying out ( possibly significant work ) on the IO threads cause
  the `io_service` any grief?

And less specifically: any other issues I should be thinking about.

Comment: it's not clear to me what you mean by calling back into `boost::asio` from a worker thread. I would expect all worker threads to add additional work to the `io_service` otherwise the event processing loop (`io_service::run()`) will terminate.

Comment: @Sam, thanks - I think I'm probably worrying too much about that particular point. I'll edit the question. I guess the thing I'm really concerned about is doing too much work inside the worker threads.

Answer (score 1):

> Does carrying out ( possibly significant work ) on the IO threads
>   cause the io_service any grief?

It really depends what you mean by grief. Performing long running operations in a handler invoked by an `io_service` can block additional handlers from being invoked by the `io_service`. Consider the simplest example with a single thread invoking `io_service::run()`. If the handler invoked by an asynchronous operation, say `async_read()` then performs some database operations that could be long running, additional outstanding asynchronous operations will not have their handlers invoked until the long running operation is complete and the handler returns control to the `io_service`.

This is typically mitigated by invoking `io_service::run()` from multiple threads, and using a `strand` to ensure exclusive access to handlers that used shared data. Though if all of your handlers perform some long running operations, you might need to investigate alternative designs.